# Output Random Value From Array

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
  let gemStones = [
  "Amethyst",
  "Diamond",
  "Emerald",
  "Ruby",
  "Sapphire",
  "Topaz",
  "Onyx",
];

let randomGemStone = gemStones[Math.floor(Math.random()*gemStones.length)];

function findGems()
{
  console.log("You found a " + randomGemStone + "!");
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <title>1. Gem Pond</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Gem Pond</h1>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <button id="gemPond_btn" onclick="findGems()">GET GEM</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the "GET GEM" button several times in a row, I always get the same result instead of getting a random one.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about turning `randomGemStone` into a function? `randomGemStone = () =>`? then call that in `findGems`? `console.log("You found a " + randomGemStone() + "!");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `let randomGemStone` line *into* the `findGems` function:

```js
function findGems()
{
  let randomGemStone = gemStones[Math.floor(Math.random()*gemStones.length)];
  console.log("You found a " + randomGemStone + "!");
}
```

Otherwise you run it only once on page load and not every time you click the button.

Comment: If `randomGemStone` value will not change you can use `const` instead of `let`

Comment: Thank you. It made perfect sense once I read your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let gemStones = [
  "Amethyst",
  "Diamond",
  "Emerald",
  "Ruby",
  "Sapphire",
  "Topaz",
  "Onyx",
];


const findGems = () => {
  let randomGemStone = gemStones[Math.floor(Math.random()*gemStones.length)];
  console.log(`You found a ${randomGemStone}!`);
}
```

Note I have moved randomGemStone inside the function.  Or the value will only be updated once when the script loads, this way it will be random everytime findGems() is called